# SQL Server Logs UpdateHadronTruncationLsn

Tags: sql-server

I have a fresh SQL Server 2019 (with the latest cumulative updates) and I have a log message each minute or two minutes. I searched but I didn't find any clue about the source of this message.

Does someone have an idea about it ?

> UpdateHadronTruncationLsn(6) (force=0): Primary: 0:0:0 Secondary: 509122:17379:1 Partial Quorum : 0:0:0 Aggregation: 509122:17379:1 Persistent: 509122:17379:1

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Hope this is helpful)

This started for us when we updated to SQL Server 2019 CU4. (15.0.4033.1)
In short Microsoft says they will fix it with Hotfix (or CU5 ) with an option to enable/disable the TF logging for that message.

This is part of the message we got from Microsoft Support:
Our Product team is going to release a Hotfix in the near future which will add a fix so that if Trace Flag 3605 is enabled then it will log the messages.